# Find the maximum repeating number in O(n) time and O(1) extra space

Tags: arrays, sorting, counting-sort

**Find the maximum repeating number (The number that occurs the most) in O(n) time and O(1) extra space** .

I think i can use counting sort phase that maintains a count array , then it can be done in O(N) . Am i right ?

But how to handle extra space . Is there any other efficient algorithm ?

Comment: Does "maximum repeating number" mean the number that occurs the most, or the biggest that is repeated?

Comment: The number that occurs the most

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The best I can think of is a sort (`O(n*log(n))`) + one sweep over the sorted array (`O(n)`).

Comment: Are they integers? Is there any limit on the largest or smallest numbers that may occur?

Comment: yes , all are integers and there is no bound or range.

Comment: I can use count array , but it takes O(N) extra space . I want O(1) .

Comment: Cannot be done. https://www.quora.com/Given-an-array-of-integers-of-size-N-how-can-we-find-the-most-frequently-occurring-element-in-linear-time . You need O(n) time and O(k) space in most favorable interpretation, with k being number of distinct numbers. As expectation of k is to grow with n, it is not really O(1) in space.

Comment: Also http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-repeating-number-in-ok-time/. Another problem with this approach is that the original array is modified and requires another `O(n)` operation to get the original values back.

Comment: if we don't want to modify the array , then it cannot be done . But what if we are allowed to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible without any further knowledge about the possible numbers in the array. For the intuition consider the following: for any constant amount of memory you are prepared to use (`c = O(1)`) there is a sequence such that at point `n-1` there are `c+1` possibilites for the correct answer and only the last number breaks the tie. In this case the algorithm with constant memory `c` cannot find the answer in one pass. This works similarly for several (constant amount of) passes.

Lets see what we can do instead.

- If we know that there are at most `k` unique numbers, we can find the answer in `O(n)` with `O(k)` extra space by keeping a count-array (or unordered map with constant lookup cost if the `k` numbers need not be sequential). But if we cannot bound `k` other than `k<n` this becomes `O(n)` extra space in the worst case.
- If we sort the array in `O(n log(n))`, we can then find the answer in `O(n)`. So the total complexity is `O(n log(n))` with `O(1)` extra space.

Comment: what about maintaining count array in O(n) and O(k) extra space .

Comment: @stackuser you are right. I was thinking of a map (which has `O(log(k))` complexity for lookup) but a unordered map or array (for sequential numbers like `0` through `k`) have constant lookup complexity.